# Get the Sum of a column grouped by another column then grouped into another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've been trying for a while now to figure this out but my lack of more advanced SQL skills are holding me back.

```
Executions(TradeDate, Symbol, Side, Price, Under, Account)

TEMP DATA:
2012-06-20, AAPL 120716C00600000, BUY, 3.25, AAPL, XYZ123
2012-06-20, AAPL 120716C00600000, SELL, 3.30, AAPL, XYZ123
2012-06-20, AAPL 120716C00600000, BUY, 3.25, AAPL, XYZ123
2012-06-20, AAPL 120716C00600000, SELL, 3.30, AAPL, XYZ123
2012-06-20, GRPN 120716C00027000, BUY, 2.25, GRPN, XYZ123
2012-06-20, GRPN 120716C00027000, SELL, 2.30, GRPN, XYZ123
2012-06-20, GRPN 120716C00027000, SELL, 2.30, GRPN, XYZ123
2012-06-20, GRPN 120716C00027000, BUY, 2.25, GRPN, XYZ123


-UNDER----Side(Buy)----Side(Sell)
 AAPL      6.50         6.60
 GRPN      4.50         4.60
```

As you can see I'm trying to get the SUM of the Price for each Side and then grouped by the Under.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` to group by `Under` column and `CASE` associated with `SUM` to get the needed results:

```
SELECT e.Under,
       SUM(case when e.Side = 'BUY' them e.Price else 0 end) as 'Side(Buy)',
       SUM(case when e.Side = 'SELL' them e.Price else 0 end) as 'Side(Sell)'
FROM Executions e
GROUP BY e.Under
```

Comment: Yes, I had to wait 9mins before I could.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for this.  (See [SQL Fiddle for Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0dc1e/1))

```
select *
from 
(
    select under, price, side
    from executions
) x
PIVOT
(
    sum(price)
    for side in ([BUY], [SELL])
) p
```

Comment: Which is more efficient using Case or Pivot?

Comment: I just looked at the execution plan for both and they appear about the same for this query since there are only two columns.  I typically use `PIVOT` for these types of queries because you have the ability to make them dynamic so you don't have to code for each column.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```
SELECT e.under
     , SUM(CASE WHEN e.side = 'BUY'  THEN e.price ELSE NULL END) AS [Side(Buy)]
     , SUM(CASE WHEN e.side = 'SELL' THEN e.price ELSE NULL END) AS [Side(Sell)]
  FROM Executions e
 GROUP BY e.under
```

The "trick" here is to use a CASE expression to return the Price only for certain values of side.
(NOTE: As someone will inevitably point out, the ELSE NULL is implicit, and can be omitted.)

This isn't the only approach. But it's a flexible approach that works very well if you also need to also get, for example, a "count" of the rows included in each of the sum, along with a count of all rows. To illustrate this approach being exercised:

```
 SELECT e.under
     , SUM(CASE WHEN e.side = 'BUY'  THEN e.price ELSE NULL END) AS [SUM_Side(Buy)]
     , SUM(CASE WHEN e.side = 'BUY'  THEN 1       ELSE 0    END) AS [COUNT_Side(Buy)]
     , SUM(CASE WHEN e.side = 'SELL' THEN e.price ELSE NULL END) AS [SUM_Side(Sell)]
     , SUM(CASE WHEN e.side = 'SELL' THEN 1       ELSE 0    END) AS [COUNT_Side(Sell)]
     , SUM(CASE WHEN e.side IN ('BUY','SELL') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [COUNT_(Buy+Sell)]
  FROM Executions e
 GROUP BY e.under
```

This approach usually has very predictable performance, and it requires that the source dataset be referenced only once (in this case, a simple table reference)

This approach works in nearly every relational database. (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, Teradata, DB2, ... )

Answer (score 0):

```
 select Symbol, sum(case when side = 'BUY' THEN Price else 0 END) as [Side(Buy)], sum(case when side = 'SELL' THEN Price else 0 END) as [Side(Sell)] group by Symbol
```